# Change src/ folder to something else when yarn start

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I'm in the process of writing a web app but I constantly see something that really wakes my OCD up. The "src" folder created by create-react-app just doesn't fit well with my idea of folder structure, I'd rather put my views inside a folder called "views". I tried to search for a solution but all I found was "create a symlink". Is there any way to make create-react-app to nominate "src" with some other names?

Comment: Downvoting without apparent reasons is always an amusing experience on this SE.

Comment: you might have to get out of `CRA` boilerplate and get down to real `webpack` config file to include your custom folder structure

Comment: @Anandhu so I guess the answer is *not possible*? This is an answer, too.

Comment: I guess so. with `CRA` your `webpack.config.js` resides in `node_modules/react-scripts` folder and messing it would be noop. i could post an answer if you want or you can post one yourself. thank you

Comment: I have posted a probable answer. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `yarn run eject` your `CRA` boilerplate to Tweak with `webpack.config.js`. `yarn run eject` reveals the entire preloaders and plugins used to compile your project.

sample script from [`webpack's wiki`](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration)

```
{
    context: __dirname + "/views",
    entry: "./entry",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    }
}
```

**Important**

`yarn run eject` is a one-way road and you cannot revert back. so be careful.